# Why does my wireless connection on a Thinkpad T400 drop approximately every two minutes?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, intel-wireless

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 12.04 on my Thinkpad T400. Everything works fine except wireless connection.

The problem  with wireless connection is that my internet stops working ever 2-3mins (even though I still seems be connected with my wireless connection). My internet starts automatically after 2-3mins

Based on some of the suggestion on similar problems I have done following already

1) Set IPv6 to ignore
2) Power Management was set to off

But no luck with above two steps...

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to solve a similar issue I had:

Go to System Settings>Network>Wireless and did the following:

1) Set the Network Name to the network you want to connect to.

2) Click the Options... button, and ensure that the Connection name: is correct, the Connect automatically checkbox is checked and is Available to all users.

3) Click on the IPv6 Settings tab and set the Method: to Ignore.

4) Click on the Wireless Security tab, and type in your security key/passcode in the Key: field.

5) Save all changes by clicking the Save... button when done.

I found that after making the above changes my Intel 5100 agn wifi connection remained stable after initial connection.